# Using the objectAtIndex method in a switch block

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode, latitude-longitude

I have an array of lattitudes and longitudes in my array,

```
NSArray *anArrayOfFloatObjects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  [NSNumber numberWithDouble:pinLocation1.latitude],
                                  [NSNumber numberWithDouble:pinLocation1.longitude],
                                  [NSNumber numberWithDouble:pinLocation2.latitude],
                                  [NSNumber numberWithDouble:pinLocation2.longitude],
                                  [NSNumber numberWithDouble:pinLocation3.latitude],
                                  [NSNumber numberWithDouble:pinLocation3.longitude],
                                  nil];
```

What I want to do is use a `switch` statement to go through the array (i.e. objectAtIndex..)

```
   switch (self.anArrayOfFloatObjects objectAtIndex:) {
        case :0
        //switch the pin color to red
            break;
        case :2
        //switch pin color to green
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

This obviously doesnt work. Does anyone know any other way?

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but your array structure looks a bit odd - you will presumably be pulling off the latitude and longitude for each pin from consecutive elements in the array.  I would put the lat and long in an array for each pin, then put those arrays into an array.

Comment: Thanks. Good point. This was just for my homework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is

```
[anArrayOfFloatObjects indexOfObject:number]
```

Maybe this code will help:

```
NSArray *anArrayOfFloatObjects; //Your array

for (NSNumber *number in anArrayOfFloatObjects) {

    switch ([anArrayOfFloatObjects indexOfObject:number]) {
        case :0
            //switch the pin color to red
            break;
        case :2
            //switch pin color to green
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Following @MikeS comment you can do something like this:

```
for (int index = 0; index < [anArrayOfFloatObjects count]; index++) {
    switch (index) {
        case :0
            //switch the pin color to red
            break;
        case :2
            //switch pin color to green
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Avoiding the need of calling `[anArrayOfFloatObjects indexOfObject:number]`

Comment: That adds an unnecessary method call. A standard `for` loop would be better: `for(int index = 0; index < anArrayOfFloatObjects.length; index++) { ... }`. Then you don't need to call `indexOfObject:` because you already have the index. You can get `number` with: `NSNumber *number = anArrayOfFloatObjects[index];`

Comment: You are right. I was focused on showing the indexOfObject method and forgot that. I'll edit my answer, thank you @MikeS

Answer (score 2):

try fast enumeration

```
for(id item in anArrayOfFloatObjects){
    NSLog(@"%@", item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also look into NSArray's `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock`.

```
[yourArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"Index: %ld - Object: %@", idx, obj);
}];
```